# Elegant solution to parse date

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I want to parse some text into a date. However, there is no guarantee that the text has the desired format. It may be `2012-12-12` or `2012` or even .

Currently, I am down the path to nested try-catch blocks, but that's not a good direction (I suppose).

```
LocalDate parse;
try {
    parse = LocalDate.parse(record, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd"));
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    try {
        Year year = Year.parse(record);
        parse = LocalDate.from(year.atDay(1));
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e2) {
        try {
              // and so on 
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e3) {}
    }
}
```

What's an elegant solution to this problem? Is it possible to use `Optional`s which is absent in case a exception happened during evaluation? If yes, how?

Comment: you should use for array to keep all your formates.

Comment: In one of the first Macs you could even type in "tomorrow", "Tuesday" and so on.

Comment: u can use pojava library if more functionality is required... like handling dd-MM-yyyy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class contains the building blocks to make this work:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("[uuuu[-MM[-dd]]]")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, now.getYear())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, now.getMonthValue())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, now.getDayOfMonth())
    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2015-06-30", fmt));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2015-06", fmt));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2015", fmt));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("", fmt));
```

The [`parseDefaulting()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) method allows a default value to be set for a specific field. In all cases, a `LocalDate` can be parsed from the result, because enough information is available.

Note also the use of "[...]" sections in the pattern to define what is optional.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to make `System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2015-06-00", fmt));` work too? So that day `00` defaults to `now.getDayOfMonth()`?

Comment: If you use a the lenient resolver style you can make it parse to 2015-05-31. But you can't achieve what you want exactly without limiting something else.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in an elegant fashion using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) optional sections. An optional section is started by the `[` token and is ended by the `]` token.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy[-MM-dd]]");
System.out.println(formatter.parse("2012-12-12")); // prints "{},ISO resolved to 2012-12-12"
System.out.println(formatter.parse("2012")); // prints "{Year=2012},ISO"
System.out.println(formatter.parse("")); // prints "{},ISO"
```

Comment: yeah thats nice. However, `formatter.parse("2012")` will throw an exception, because its not compatible with `LocalDate` when no day and month is given

Comment: @helt No it will not, a Year object will be created. DateTimeFormatter does not always build a LocalDate, it builds a generic TemporalAccessor. You can test my code to convince yourself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And afterwards, i carefully craft my own LocalDate using `TemporalAccessor.isSupported`, right? Or is there a better solution, too? ;)

Comment: Do you really need a LocalDate? If so, how 2012 should be represented as LocalDate (January the 1st)?

Comment: no i do not really need LocalDate. I just dont know any class class thats is better suited to store a date with a "confidence interval" around it. e.g. "Somewhere in 2010" or "24-12-2010 +- 4 weeks"